# Is the automorphism group of a normal affine scheme a group scheme or an algebraic space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, birational-geometry

If $ \operatorname{Spec}(A) $ is a smooth affine scheme over an algebraically closed field $ k $, then is $ \operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Spec}(A)) $ a group scheme or an algebraic space?

Please include a reference if you know of one.

Comment: The automorphism group functor, defined in the usual way, is almost never representable for affine schemes; it is neither representable as a scheme nor as an algebraic space.  If you want a different definition, please specify the definition that you use.

Comment: You might have a look at *On some infinite-dimensional groups. II* by Shafarevich, Mathematics of the USSR-Izvestiya, 1982, 18:1, 185–194. He defines a notion of
 "infinite-dimensional algebraic groups", which includes for instance $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{A}^n) $ for $n\geq 2$.

Comment: I remember the example of the ``shear'' $(x,y)\mapsto(x,y+p(x))$ where $p(x)$ is any polynomial, an infinite dimensional family of automorphisms of the plane.

Comment: There is a cardinality argument that proves that the group functor is *not* represented by a scheme (unless we take the quotient by all possible nilpotent structures, as indicated by Friedrich Knop below).  The usual group functor has $k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$-points (at the group identity) that form a countably infinite dimensional $k$-vector space.  Yet if the functor is representable, then this equals the $k$-vector space dual of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$.  As the dual of an infinite-dimensional $k$-vector space, this should have uncountable dimension.

Answer (score 6):

The automorphism group functor is always represented by an affine ind-scheme, i.e. a union of a countable chain of closed affine subschemes of finite type. See the paper Furter, Kraft:  On the geometry of the automorphism groups of affine varieties, arxiv:1809.0417. It treats only the reduced part of $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ with $\mathrm{char}k=0$, though.